# Notification not going away

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have this Notification Component in the React.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IoMdClose } from "react-icons/io";


export type NotificationValueType = {
  message: string;
  type: "success" | "error";
};

type NotificationProps = {
  message: string;
  type?: "success" | "error" | "warning";
  duration?: number;
  onClose?: () => void;
  index?: number;
};

const Notification: React.FC<NotificationProps> = ({
  message,
  type = "success",
  duration = 3000,
  onClose,
  index = 0,
}) => {
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(true);

  let notificationColor = "bg-green-500";
  if (type === "error") {
    notificationColor = "bg-red-500";
  } else if (type === "warning") {
    notificationColor = "bg-orange-400";
  }

  const alertClasses = `${notificationColor} z-50 fixed top-4 left-1/2 text-base transform -translate-x-1/2 max-w-sm w-full text-white p-2 pl-6 rounded-sm flex justify-between items-center`;
  const dynamicTopClass = `mt-${index * 12}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowAlert(false);
      if (onClose) {
        onClose();
      }
    }, duration);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [duration, onClose]);

  return showAlert ? (
    <div className={`${alertClasses} ${dynamicTopClass}`}>
      <p>{message}</p>
      <IoMdClose
        className="cursor-pointer font-extrabold text-xl text-gray-light hover:text-white"
        onClick={onClose}
      />
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default Notification;
```

Not the best component, but I am refactoring it as I am building my app. The problem I am facing now is that the notification doesn't close after 3 seconds if the user is still interacting with the app. For example, the notification will show up, and if the user is just scrolling the page and not clicking any buttons for the 3 seconds, then the notification disappears. But if the user is pressing different buttons, or interacting with the app, the notification stays, and it only goes away if the user stops interacting with the app for 3 seconds.

I tried asking ChatGPT, but it didn't work out. It was advising me to create a useState and use that to trigger my useEffect which triggers the timer.

Is there a cleaner and better way to achieve this? I just want the notification to go away after 3 seconds, even though the user is interacting with the app.

Thank you guys.

Comment: This happens most probably due to the browser main thread is busy so that your settimeout logic doesn't get the chance to be executed. You may try handling your notification hiding logic inside a worker thread. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: .., or you may use a notification library that handles all these cases for you OOTB. Some popular libraries are https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify, https://react-hot-toast.com/ etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was ever to resolve this by removing this,
`return () => clearTimeout(timer);`

The clearTimeout was canceling the execution of a function that was previously scheduled to run after a specified time using setTimeout.

By removing it, I was able to make it work.